# Database inaccessible when Exporting

Tags: mysql, export

I am exporting a MySQL database that is currently in use by an application, but when I start the process the database becomes inaccessible and the application does not work, so I had to terminate the export process to allow the application to use it again. As the application is live, I cant let it go offline. Is this a normal thing, that MySQL database doesn't work when being exported, or do I need to do something in particular to export it this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `mysqldump`? Sounds like your tables are being locked.

Are you working with `InnoDB` tables? If you are using `mysqldump`, I'd look into the `--single-transaction` option. That will take a snapshot, but the key thing to remember is that any data changed during the export will not be reflected in the output. It will be in the production `db`, just not in the export until next time.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction

Comment: yes I am using innodb, seems like yes, that single transaction option should do the thing here, will check